# Shutdown raspberry from Tomcat app

Tags: web-server, root

I have an app running on a Tomcat Server. On a certain situation I want to shutdown my raspberry using the command `shutdown -h now`. So far, I've tried this:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo shutdown -h now");
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Error trying to shutdown raspberry : " + e.getMessage());
}
```

The app runs, no exception caught but raspberry keeps turned on. Do I need to do something else to make it work? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

> The app runs, no excpetion caught but raspberry keeps turned on.

Just because the `exec` call didn't throw an exception,
that doesn't mean the command work.
The `exec` call returns a `Process` instance,
you should check the exit code to verify the command actually worked.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo shutdown -h now");
if (process.exitValue() != 0) {
    logger.error("command failed");
}
```

> Do I need to do something else to make it work? Is it possible at all?

As what user is the Tomcat process running?
If it's not `root`, then you need to configure `/etc/sudoers` to let that user execute `shutdown` without password.